# No funciona prompt ni alert

Tags: alert, prompt

he probado  a ejecutar en el apartado que hay para insertar código(<>) y me ha funcionado  pero en mi  index.html no sale el alert ni el prompt no sé por qué será, no se si será porque es linux mi pc , ni idea.

```js
 var nota1 = parseFloat(prompt("Introduzca el primer numero"))

alert("eeeeeee");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>entreno</title>
    <link href="entreno.js">
    


</head>

<body>

<h1>Hola que tal</h1>




<script type="text/javascript" src="entreno.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pues no sé cual es el problema, porque al ejecutar tu ejemplo si que funciona... has puesto bien la ruta a tu archivo .js? Y por qué la tienes duplicada?? `<link>` y `<script>`

Comment: dices que ponga el nombre de la carpeta en la que esta el html y js ? porque lo pongo y no funciona tampoco seria src="entrenoo/entreno.js "y no funciona tampoco :S

Comment: @sergiom Primero, bienvenido a stack overflow, lo segundo, si quieres importar archivos de js se haría de la siguiente manera: `<script src="loquesea.js"></script>` e n vez de cómo tú lo has hecho en un inicio `<link href="entreno.js">`.